# SQL count occurrences of certain categories that rows belong to

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have this table with some data:

```
table ColorsFlavors

id | name | color | flavor
--------------------------
 1 | n1   | green | lemon
 2 | n2   | blue  | strawberry
 3 | n3   | red   | lemon
 4 | n4   | green | lemon
 5 | n5   | green | mango
 6 | n6   | red   | chocolate
 7 | n7   | white | lemon
 8 | n8   | blue  | mango
 9 | n9   | green | chocolate
```

I wish to make a SQL query (or queries?) that lets me get the total number of rows with each color, and the total number of rows with each flavour.

Something like this:

```
colors | occurrences
--------------------
green  |   4
blue   |   2
red    |   6
white  |   1


flavor    | occurences
----------------------
lemon     |   4
strawberry|   1
mango     |   2
chocolate |   2
```

Uhmmm what about too if I have a predefined list of colors and flavors to pick from, so that colors/flavors that don't occur on the data table get a 0 count?

```
colors | occurrences
--------------------
green  |   4
blue   |   2
red    |   6
white  |   1
black  |   0


flavor    | occurences
----------------------
lemon     |   4
strawberry|   1
mango     |   2
chocolate |   2
cherry    |   0
```

So, what would be the SQL queries to retrieve those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do all the colors in the ColorsFlavors table

```
Select
  cf.Color,
  Count(*)
From
  ColorsFlavors cf
Group By
  cf.Color
```

If you have a predefined list in a table (which I'll call Colors), and you want to include zeros:

```
Select
  c.Color,
  Coalesce(Count(*), 0)
From
  Colors c
    Left Outer Join
  ColorsFlavors cf
    On c.Color = cf.Color
Group By
  c.Color
```

If you have a predefined list that somebody typed in

```
Select
  c.Color,
  Coalesce(Count(*), 0)
From  (
    Select 'green' As Color Union All
    Select 'blue' Union All
    Select 'red' Union All
    Select 'white' Union All
    Select 'black'
  ) c
    Left Outer Join
  ColorsFlavors cf
    On c.Color = cf.Color
Group By
    c.Color
```

With this you should be able to work out flavours!

Comment: well, there's no Colors table, but maybe I can 'simulate' one via a join?

Comment: @JavierNovoaC. You said what if you had a predefined list of colors to choose from. Where are you getting them from?

Comment: @JavierNovoaC. I've put some more options in.