# jasper report count occurrencies of certain categories

Tags: count, jasper-reports, ireport, summary

I have already tried to count the occurrencies of certain categories that rows belong to (see [SQL count occurrences of certain categories that rows belong to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426617/sql-count-occurrences-of-certain-categories-that-rows-belong-to))

But now I'm wondering if, without doing the sql thing, is jasper reports capable of all this? doing the summaries on its own without giving the database server extra work (that what's actually happening to me)?

For example, this may be the report I have:

```
name | color | flavor
--------------------------
n1   | green | lemon
n2   | blue  | strawberry
n3   | red   | lemon
n4   | green | lemon
n5   | green | mango
n6   | red   | chocolate
n7   | white | lemon
n8   | blue  | mango
n9   | green | chocolate
```

And this would be a summary I would like to get:

```
colors | occurrences         flavor    | occurences
--------------------         ----------------------
green  |   4                 lemon     |   4
blue   |   2                 strawberry|   1
red    |   6                 mango     |   2
white  |   1                 chocolate |   2
```

Answer (score 2):

you have 3 options:

1. Have 2 sub reports and in each order select by color and flavor. And in each sub report summary have them as part of master summery. When SQL data comes ordered you can in iReport create group per that columns and in variable count each group. Disadvantage is that you go 2 times to DB for each sub report.
2. Have own java implementation of data source. Which simply will be like a data proxy not doing any data conversion. Only having HashMap counting occurence of color and flavor. Then as additional field with report evaluation "Report" get this fields from data source and have them on report. You go to DB just once.
3. Combination with print if expression and defined groups (color,flavor) with print if expression could help together with union ALL select statements: 


   select a,b,c 'print_to_detail' as print_if_field, ' ' as dummy_field 
   **union all**

   select a,b,c 'print_to_group1_summary' as print_if_field, color as dummy_field order by color

   **union all**

   select a,b,c 'print_to_group2_summary' as print_if_field, flavor as dummy_field order by color

Maybe this helps as conceptual idea.

Comment: 1. that's exactly the problem I'm facing using extra SQL queries to generate the summaries. Since I must query the DB an extra pair of times, I'm getting a lot of DBserver load used and that's what I'm trying to reduce by giving the charge on to jasper...

Comment: 2. the same reason for me not being able to mangle with the dbserver applies here, I cannot mangle with the application server, and I'm not able to make my own java data sources too. This is just a server that lets me upload .jasper reports with predefined SQL queries on it, but not anything else. I'm trying to find a way (if there exists one) of letting jasper take the full control of the summary I'm pretending to generate in my report...

Comment: So then maybe combination with print if expression and defined groups (color,flavor) with print if expression could help together with union ALL select statements:

Comment: Added paragraph numbered as #3. to answer as answer to comments.

Comment: wouldn't solution #3 imply 3 queries just united and all? I guess performance and DBServer load will be hit a lot, just as with the subreports solutions, isn't that what UNION do?